# WPF Bind to derived object property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, prism, wpfdatagrid

I have abstract class Vehicle, and from that 3 concrete class are inherited i.e.Boat, Car and Aeroplane.

Now I have collection of a object which has ID, Quantity and Vehicle

```
class data
{
    public int ID {get; set}
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
    public Vehicle Vehicle {get; set;}
}
```

Now I have a collection of data i.e. `IEnumerable<data>` in ViewModel

And I am binding this to the Datagrid.

Now some properties CAR object might have which Aeroplane and boat object might not have and vice versa.

How can I identify which concrete object is there in the collection and accordingly show in the description column.

For CAR i want to show data from property REVIEW.
For Aeroplane I want to show data from property NOTES and similarly for boat.

All the above property data should come in the "Description" column of DataGrid

Can someone please help?

Comment: I removed my answer since it doesn't work with `DataTemplate` inside `CellTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

Add an abstract Description property to the Vehicle class, and make sure the classes that inherit from the class put the proper information in to that. Then the UI will have something consistent to bind to.

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
    public abstract string Description { get; }
}

class Aeroplane : Vehicle
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public override string Description => Notes;
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public string Review { get; set; }
    public override string Description => Review;
}

class Boat : Vehicle
{
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public override string Description => Notes;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go if you control the classes, you you don't mind adding an extra property that is only used in the View, and you don't need to worry about that values in that column changing (raising the property changed notification can be a pain).  This works really well for simple cases.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I always assume they are in control... and I see now that I shouldn't always do that. Thanks!

Comment: We can do this even using converter I suppose.

Comment: An `IValueConverter` would work too.  It would require binding the column to the instance itself, as in my answer, with `{Binding Path=.}.`.  It's a nice middle-ground between our 2 answers. No need to modify the data classes, and the XAML doesn't get hugely inflated.

Comment: So, you are thinking that you would check the object type, and return the appropriate property? How many different scenarios (types) would you run into? Or, do you have something else in mind?